# Does socketio allow to send live video stream or blob?

Tags: socket.io, video-streaming, webrtc

I would like to know if socketio can be used to send live stream(localmedia stream) to other peer in the room without support of webRTC. In clear I want to use socketio for videochat not for signalling.

If possible I would like to know how reliable it can be and does server take the live video stream load.

Thank you

Comment: Read this: http://phoboslab.org/log/2013/09/html5-live-video-streaming-via-websockets.  Many other articles to read in a Google search for "socket.io video streaming".

Comment: Yes, socket.io has binary support: http://socket.io/blog/introducing-socket-io-1-0/#binary.  Also see [socket.io-stream](http://socket.io/blog/introducing-socket-io-1-0/#socket.io-stream) on the same page.

Comment: Where are you @MadhukarC?  I gave you some significant information and I've heard nothing back from you 17 hours later!

Comment: I've been working on doing something similar and can't figure out how to do what madhukarc is trying to do. I've basically been trying to send the blob url to other connected clients and it 404's on all of them except the one that it originated. I can't find any code examples on how to take the localmedia stream or blob and convert them to binary to be sent across... Any suggestions, @jfiend00 ?